# How to make the shared value behave consistently without mutex?

Tags: c++, multithreading, atomic

I have the following code. I do not understand why the reader sees inconsistent variable value.

```
uint64_t get_counter() {
    static uint64_t counter = 0;
    static std::mutex m;
    std::unique_lock l(m);
    return ++counter;
}

auto main() -> int {
    // uint64_t shared = 0;
    std::atomic<uint64_t> shared = 0;

    const auto writer = [&shared]() -> void {
        while (true) {
            shared = get_counter();
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    };
    const auto reader = [&shared]() -> void {
        while (true) {
            const uint64_t local = shared;
            if (local > shared) {
                cout << local << " " << shared << endl;
            }
            std::this_thread::yield();
        }
    };

    std::thread w1(writer), w2(writer), r(reader);
    r.join();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

`get_counter` is just a helper to generate strictly increasing numbers. In reality it could be replaced by other more useful functions.

Since `shared` should never go smaller, I expect when `if (local > shared)` is evaluated, it should never be true. However, I'm getting output like these:

```
1022 1960
642677 644151
645309 645699
1510591 1512122
1592957 1593959
7964226 7965790
8918667 8919962
9094127 9095161
9116800 9117780
9214842 9215720
9539737 9541144
9737821 9739100
10222726 10223912
11197862 11199348
```

Looks like `local` was indeed smaller than `shared`, but then why the output? Is it caused by some data race? If so, how to fix this without introducing mutex? Can `std::atomic_thread_fence` be used to help? Does `shared` have to be a `std::atomic`?

Comment: The values returned by `get_counter()` should be sequential but there is no guarantee that they're written into `shared` in sequential order. You could just increment `shared` directly which would give sequential outputs

Comment: Is there a way to "increment `shared` directly` without putting mutex in the main function, which is what I'm trying to avoid? The mutex in `get_counter` is just for the demonstration.

Comment: just `shared++`?

Comment: Do you have to process every single value you get form `get_counter`? For example, if writer1 gets 10 from `get_counter` and writer2 gets 8, but tries to write after writer1, do you still want to set shared to 8 or can you discard that call to `get_counter` and retry (effectively skipping the 8 you just got)?

Comment: Are you aware that the value of `shared` in the `if` condition and the one sent to `cout` may be different?

Comment: Yes. That explains weirdness of the printed numbers. It is because there could be many executions of the writers between `if` and `cout`. I guess it is because `cout` is a "costly" operation, and OS by default tries to give each thread "fairness" of run time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Seems to me like the following sequence is possible:

```
 Writer1: get_counter() -> 2
 Writer2: get_counter() -> 3
 Writer2: shared = 3
 Reader: local = shared (3)
 Writer1: shared = 2
 Reader: if (local > shared) // 3 > 2
```

Since your lock doesn't cover the generation + assignment you have a "race condition" on the write to shared and it can be out of order from the generation, leading to the if firing.

I put race condition in quotes since it's not a data race (since shared is atomic).

Comment: Small typo: `Writer2: shared = 2` should be `Writer1: shared = 2`

Comment: OK. I understand why it fails now. But how do you suggest to fix it without introducing mutex to the main function? How to make getting `get_counter()` value and storing to `shared` one atomic operation? I thought that's what `std::atomic` supposed to guarantee.

Comment: @CrendKing why do you even have get_counter()? Why not just trigger `shared++` or `fetch_add(1)`?

Comment: @ALX23z to quote OP here: *get_counter is just a helper to generate strictly increasing numbers. In reality it could be replaced by other more useful functions*

Comment: @CrendKing the atmoic part of this just guarantees that the held value is always in a valid state (i.e. no threads can write to the stored object at the same time). The function call to `get_counter` is **not** part of this guarantee. Try to inline the function (i.e. copy paste the whole function body before the assignment) and think about the implications of it, if `atomic` had to guarantee that all this new code is atmoic in regards to the assignment at the end.

Answer (score 4):

Conceptually, time passes between when `get_counter()` returns (unlocking its lock) and when the returned value is stored in `shared`.  In that interval, the other thread could complete a call to `get_counter()` and store that (larger) returned value in `shared`, possibly many times.  Then the first thread stores the value it originally got from `get_counter()`, which is smaller.

For example:

```
Writer 1                  Writer 2                 Reader
Call get_counter()
get_counter() returns 5
                          Call get_counter()
                          get_counter returns 6
                          store 6 in shared
                                                   load 6 from shared
store 5 in shared
                                                   load 5 from shared
```

The store to `shared` should really be protected by the same lock as `counter`, or some similar measure taken to ensure that `shared` is not written by any other thread before the counter value can be stored.

Fences can't help here.  They deal with the situation where loads and stores in one thread become visible to another thread in an order that isn't the first thread's program order.  In this case, you have a race even if every operation takes place in precisely the order that it appears in your source.